# Is it possible for a concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor worker to live on beyond its parent

Tags: python

I am encountering a bug where the workers in a process pool executor are living on after the death of the main process. How is this possible?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Is a context manager used?